# MySql Query to return number of photos in each album

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

My table is set up like this, all I need to do is call a query to my Photos table.

I have PhotoID as the primary key and GalleryID as the foreign key to Gallery. How can I count the number of unique PhotoID's for each multiple GalleryIDs.

So to speak there are may duplicate GalleryIDs because there are many photos in a gallery. So I just need to could the number of unique PhotoIDs associated with that GalleryID.

Can it be done in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT GalleryID, count(PhotoID)
FROM Photos
GROUP BY GalleryID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use JOIN and GROUP BY clauses like so:

```
SELECT `Gallery`.`GalleryID`, COUNT(`Photos`.`PhotoID`) AS `NumOfPhotos` FROM `Gallery`
LEFT JOIN `Photos` ON `Gallery`.`GalleryID` = `Photos`.`GalleryID`
GROUP BY `Gallery`.`GalleryID`;
```

This will count the number of Photos.PhotoID entries grouped by the Gallery Id.

In this case, you could do the query without the JOIN, by just querying the Photos table, but if you want more than just the GalleryID from the gallery table, you need the join.

Answer (score 0):

uses the following sql

```
select count(photoid) as noOfPhotos from photos group by galleryid;
```

use where on galleryid to get result for specific gallerie(s)